# Retrieve data from Galaxy A3 with broken screen and touch

Tags: contacts, backup, restore, broken-screen, samsung-galaxy-a3

there is any possibility to restore data from my phone (Samsung Galaxy A3)?
It has a broken screen and touch. I didn't enable a debuging mode on phone before. So programs like dr.fone or kies cant get acces. :c the only thing I need are contacts. I didn't enable a Gmail synchronization also so I don't have them in google cloud.

Comment: You could see about getting the screen repaired.